# How to properly call a method with generic parameter from abstract Parent class when herited child instance type is UnionType?

Tags: typescript

I can't figure out to properly solve the issue I'm facing right now without implementing if check:

```
type ClassicRecord = {
    recordType: "classic";
    classicField: string;
}

type SplitRecord = {
    recordType: "split";
    splitField: number;
}

type RecordType = ClassicRecord | SplitRecord


abstract class Parent<U> {
    abstract _type: string;
    records: U[] = []

    public add(record: U) {
        this.records.push(record)
    }
}

class Classic extends Parent<ClassicRecord>{
    readonly _type = "classic";


}

class Split extends Parent<SplitRecord> {
    readonly _type = "split";
}

type Measurement = Classic | Split

const getMeasurement = (): Measurement => {
    if (Math.random() > 0.5) return new Classic();
    return new Split();
}

const getRecord = (): RecordType => {
    if (Math.random() > 0.5) return { recordType: "split", splitField: 33 }
    return { recordType: "classic", classicField: "33" }
}

const measurement = getMeasurement()


const record = getRecord()

// Argument of type 'RecordType' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
//  The intersection 'ClassicRecord & SplitRecord' was reduced to 'never' because property 
// 'recordType' has conflicting types in some constituents.
//    Type 'ClassicRecord' is not assignable to type 'never'.
measurement.add(record)
```

Of course I can solve this using if check:

```
if (measurement instanceof Split) {
    if (record.recordType === "split") {
        measurement.add(record)
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=60&ssc=2&pln=56&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgNgQwM5IJYGMBKF0HsBOAJlALxQDeAUFDVPjgYQCrgQBcUAROoihpwG5qtHsjToAYqghxCHJMHyoAdgHMhAX0qVQkKAGUwcVMGx4ipCsJr1zzVh05IjJwdajPjwKTLlRlAK4AtgBGEPia2rrQZowsemTwYhixFgA+Bi6mDETalAghCvgI6MBQoihQAAoI9MrAADwAqgB8VrRQBUUlZQD60fKKKurutoxIHE0A2gC6lrPaHWABIcbonYSEABRjRJMAlO0dtMAAFqhIAHS7hFfLSKc7OYT77lpalBVIsLziUBAAD2AEGUt2qtRBjSSfCwzxaVA69AQhFwyjgICg-VYlm4v34Qm0Hy+mS8-yBILBNTqjUMXlShDaCNoSJRaIxWISXE8rkiOmxAFkIMgAvQgpDLNC-hlaSZtHhlAooKoIMBBcLReKyFt9hw1UgRRAxfVSIz3KgAGZQLb8hBna4IUG4ILaqBtAAMlwArId6MARcp-BAAO4-ZLobVCREq-2BkMy4ARyhE1GK5XZOyWbUcenxaAkU0dC1Wm124qO52Hd1en3R-AB8h0Z65xzc4CcAA0HiyPlkHAAzH2oFoo366xRG3Zm1wvvxOzPJNJe1wB5wh0m5SmymL1YbNUqVXqDUaE68NwqyjdLGn6dq8gB6O-KXBlIMEADWw0o2-1Gvql2R2w3KelAPq++AfmolBFls35HuKKgKA66AQLglrxocTI0NBNzXE22IkARXJZJwGHuB0sG-sA-6bE8divB07x5EAA)

But I wonder if there is a elegant manner to solve this using TypeScript?

Maybe my structure is not the right way to implement this?

Comment: Change the return type: https://tsplay.dev/w2vDrw

Comment: @kelsny, it work perfectly. thank you